# could not load assembly 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sqlite

I'm trying to update an existing code base so it functions on Android N. 
At the moment a file SQLite.cs is using DllImports to link sqlite3 commands to a native library libsqlite.so which is no longer allowed and generates an error:
'libmonosgen-2.0.so: unauthorized access to "/system/lib/libsqlite.so"'

To get past this I have added a new reference using the Nuget Package Manager called SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN that contains the class SQLiteApiAndroidN which has the sqlite3 methods I need to replace those in my problem file.

My namespaces:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using SQLite.Net.Interop;
using SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid;
```

Instantiating the class:

```
public static class SQLThree
{
    public static SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidN sqlite = new SQLiteApiAndroidN();
}
```

An example of the object being used to open a database:

```
var r = SQLThree.sqlite.Open (databasePathAsBytes, out handle, (int) openFlags, IntPtr.Zero);
```

When I go to build this solution I get the following error:

Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

File name: 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   SIMSMobileView

The SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN.dll is located in my packages folder in the project. The reference is added to the references of the right project file. Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this error? I'm pretty new to c# and Xamarin and generally program Android apps in Java natively, but I was handed this project to update; so apologies if I'm overlooking something trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Closing the solution
2. Delete all contents of the Packages folder (all the DLL's referenced through Nuget)
3. Restart the solution
4. Build (this will cause Nuget to get all DLL's again based on the packages.config)